# Stochastic simulation, what to do after generate the initial random sample

Tags: machine-learning, random-variable, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I don't have a background in statistics but currently learning the basics.
I want to do a stochastic simulation, which I assume here I should iterate my simulation multiple times. And I am stuck now on what to do next.

What I've done so far:

1. Generate random values with normal distribution, in this case, the mean, standard deviation and number of events (population) are predefined. (0.5,0.2 and 1000 respectively)
2. Iterate the simulation 100 times (100 scenarios) (not sure if the number of simulations is good)

Now I am stuck, I want to multiply each value with 100000 from population 1 to population 1000, which is derived from the best simulation scenario (out of 100 scenarios). How do I know which simulation scenario is the best one?

Note: My tool is Python

Comment: What is the purpose of the simulation?

Comment: What is a "simulation scenario"? In which sense is one "best"? What is the difference between the 100 replications in 2. (beyond sheer randomness)? Why does it matter than the code is written in Python?

Comment: @MehmetSüzen so the task is to simulate the loss ratio caused by flood, with 1000 events (here means the population), std deviation is known and the mean loss ratio is also known

Comment: @Xi'an what I meant by "simulation scenario" is the generated random value, 
the difference is just the randomness, probably there is a better tool for the calculation

Comment: Could you write the event whose probability you want to simulate via this experiment in mathematical terms? Like, e.g.,$$\text{Pr}(\bar{X}_n\ge x_0)$$if you are looking for an extreme flooding event. The term "loss ratio" need be defined precisely as well.

Answer (score 1):

[I will speculate about what you are trying to approximate by simulation.
At least the following will show one format for simulation in R that you may be
able to adapt to your work in Python.]

Suppose an individual flood has $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=5,\, \sigma=0.2).$
And suppose you want to know about the average $A =\bar X_{1000}$ of $n = 1000$ floods; in particular, you want to find $P(A > 5.01).$

Then the *exact theoretical answer* can be found by using the distribution of $A,$
which is $$A \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 5,\, \sigma=.2/\sqrt{1000}).$$
By a direct computation in R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF, we find
$P(A > 5.01) = 1 - P(A \le 5.01) = 0.0569:$

```
1 - pnorm(5.01, 5, .2/sqrt(1000))
[1] 0.05692315
```

Now suppose you are not yet familiar with the relationship for the distribution of $A,$ displayed above. And you are asked to do a *simulation
to approximate* $P(A > 5.01).$

There are various formats for doing such a simulation in R. I will illustrate one of them. A thousand iterations is not enough to get reasonable
accuracy, so I will use 100,000. Thus, the vector `a` will contain 100,000
simulated averages. The result is $P(A > 5.01) = 0.0575 \pm 0.0007.$

```
set.seed(2021)
a = replicate(10^5, mean(rnorm(1000, 5, .2)))
summary(a);  length(a);  sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.973   4.996   5.000   5.000   5.004   5.026 
[1] 100000        # sample size
[1] 0.006326662   # sample SD
mean(a > 5.01)
[1] 0.05749       # aprx P(A > 5.01)
sd(a > 5.01)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.0007361076  # aprx 95% margin of sim error
```

The logical vector `a > 5.01` has 100,000 `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s.

[image]

```
hist(a, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", 
       main="Histogram of simulated Averages")
 curve(dnorm(x, 5, .2/sqrt(1000)), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 5.01, lty="dotted", lwd=2)
```

Comment: It would be straightforward to deduce exactly how many iterations are "enough" in this setting.

Comment: Yes. And not surprisingly, I have found that $10^5$ are enough to get about two place accuracy for simulated means and probabilities, and $10^6$ often give three place accuracy.